# How can I receive image data from Web API and set it to the src of an image tag?

Tags: javascript, image, asp.net-web-api2

I need to be able to display an image that's located on a server's local hard drive, but not in a publicly served web directory.  To that end, I'm returning the image via a Web API controller.  The controller is returning an object derived from IHttpActionResult.  Right now I've got it hardcoded to just return a single image, for testing.

From what I can see, the controller endpoint is working correctly.  When I set the image tag's src tag to the URL of the endpoint, it displays on the page.  So why don't I just do that?

The problem is authorization.  My application has everything running through an authorization wrapper that adds an authorization header which carries a JSON Web Token.  Setting an image's src tag directly doesn't allow me to specify that header, so the request is denied when I have authorization turned on.

Now, I could modify the endpoint to take the JWT as a URI parameter directly, but I'd rather not do that if possible.  I'd like to continue using the authorization wrapper.

So my other option is to return the data as a response to a Javascript axios request.  I can get the data to be returned, but I've not been able to successfully set it to the image tag's src.  I know this should be possible if you correctly base64 encode the data, but no matter what I try the data doesn't make sense to the browser and I get no image.

I've tried Uint8Array, ArrayBuffer, Blob, btoa, etc., etc. to varying degrees of failure.  Most of the time it doesn't work.  A few of the tries have resulted in btoa complaining that the data doesn't fall within its expected character set.

I am returning the file as an application/octet-stream type.  With that in mind, the basic question is:  how do I take a response of that type in Javascript and turn it into something that can be set to an image tag's src and display the image?

Controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("download")]
        public IHttpActionResult Download()
        {
            string fileName = "constantvigilance.jpg";
            var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\images\constantvigilance.jpg");

   var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);
            return new FileResult(dataStream, Request, fileName);
        }
```

Result type I'm returning from the controller.

```
public class FileResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        MemoryStream data;
        string fileName;
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage;
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;
        public FileResult(MemoryStream data, HttpRequestMessage request, string filename)
        {
            this.data = data;
            httpRequestMessage = request;
            fileName = filename;
        }
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            httpResponseMessage = httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(data);

            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(httpResponseMessage);
        }
    }
```

As mentioned, from what I can tell those controller pieces are working fine and do return a valid image via REST endpoint...and if I didn't have authorization requirements, I would already be done.